# How can I prevent a <div> with a background image from collapsing upon screen resize?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm designing a Wordpress template (site), but I'm having some trouble.

Basically on every page there's a horizontal nav across the top (not fixed to the top), and right below is a 100%-width (usually about 20%vh tall) picture with some text over it. In order to put the text over it and have it be changeable, I set the picture container as a  and then added the image as a 'background-image' with CSS.

However, when I make the page smaller (testing for responsiveness), all the content below the picture collapses on it. See the pictures attached to understand what I mean.

How can I set it so the content below the big picture doesn't collapse on it when the window is made smaller? I've tried 'min-height', but it hasn't seemed to work.

HTML:

```
<div id="introParagraph" class="m-b-2 p-y-2">  <!--- THE CONTAINER DIV -->
 <h1 class="text-xs-left col-xs-10 col-md-offset-1 m-b-1">Our approach</h1>               
 <h3 class="text-xs-left col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-6 m-t-1" id="question">How we help you figure out what works for you and your business. <br><br> Click on the icons to learn more. </h3>                   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 650px){  /* I set it under media-query because the picture is grey on a mobile device-- the picture only shows on bigger screens */

#introParagraph{
  background:  url("../img/approach.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45%;
}
```

Here are pictures where you can see my 'collapsing-in' problem, and how I want it to look when it's resized:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can we see this online (or in a fiddle)?

Comment: @JoostS, you got it! Working on it now!

Comment: @JoostS https://jsfiddle.net/brandonstiles/ujt4nc0h/

Comment: Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/f7ya2n9q/1/?

Comment: @JoostS was it changing the min-height to 265px? It works on that one, but for other pages where that intro paragraph is longer, it doesn't work as well! Would I just need to go in and set a min-height for each page so that it works for that? I can do that (there's only 5 pages like that), but I thought there'd be a one-shot way of doing it...

Comment: Set a standard min-height and a proper padding bottom for the container. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set height in pixels?

Comment: That works, I am sure. But it is not very elegant nor responsive.

Comment: You can set some height for example 400px then in your media querys for phone, tablet, desktops breakpoints you can make it smaller, also you can do the same thing with %

Comment: @JoostS, you are right. I DID try to add a 'min-height' in pixels, but even that didn't work well on all the pages with the different paragraph lengths. I tried removing the height command from the CSS as well, but it also didn't work. I'm stuck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you must to increase picture height to bigger, for example to 100%, or the title font-size to smaller the when the page is smaller. Use another media jquery when the text is outside the background-image. And use clear:both to the content div under the block with the background image.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `#introParagraph` cannot grow/adjust to the size of the content due to the height setting. In other words, your container does not 'contain' / has an overflow. This is caused by the content being higher than 45% of the height of the screen. When you remove the height from the CSS statement you allow the container to grow/adjust to the height of the content.

A fixed fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/f7ya2n9q/1/